# Что означает $ в css?

Tags: css, sass

На просторах интернета наткнулся на сайт кодепэн айо так в `css` файле было написано:

```
$skin: #f5d8b4;
$black: #231f20;
$blue: #01afee;
$red: #c11d2b;
```

*что это значит*?

Comment: это был не css, а scss, и в нем это обозначения переменных

Answer (score 3):

Можете ознакомиться с [Sass](https://sass-scss.ru/guide/)

**SASS** -  *это язык похожий на HAML, но предназначенный для упрощения создания CSS-кода.* 
Собственно, `$blue: #3bbfce` - это "*переменные*"

---

Пример использования:

```
$blue: #3bbfce
$margin: 16px

.content-navigation
  border-color: $blue
  color: darken($blue, 9%)
```

[O Sass на habre](https://habrahabr.ru/post/140612/)

*Надеюсь помог!*